# Does executorService make sure to await for termination if Shutdown happens?

Tags: java, executorservice

I have the following code:

```
public class AbcThreadPool {

    private final AbcThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public InventoryAvailabilityThreadPool(final AbcRunnableFactory factory,
                                           final Integer poolSize) {
        executor = new AbcThreadPoolExecutor(factory, poolSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i) {
            executor.execute(factory.createRunnable());
        }
    }

    private static class AbcThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

        private final AbcRunnableFactory factory;

        public AbcThreadPoolExecutor(final AbcRunnableFactory factory,
                                                       final int poolSize) {
            super(poolSize, poolSize, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
            this.factory = factory;
            allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        if (!isShutdown() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            execute(factory.createRunnable());
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, will it handle the case that if the shutdown of the process happens say by Ctrl + C, it would wait for termination of threads before killing it? Or I need to add a shutdownHook for doing so to call

```
executorService.awaitTermination
```

before the program exits?

Comment: Java will not call `awaitTermination` by itself, your code will need to explicitly call it.

Comment: But is CTRL + C going to invoke the shutdown() method of executor or which method would be invoked in that case?